# Removing single quotes from variable when executing a command on a remote server

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

The following job causes some issues:

```yaml
publish:
  stage: deployment
  variables:
    SERVICE_NAME: 'data_cleaner'
  script:
    - CONTAINER_ID=$(ssh $USER@$TARGET_SERVER 'docker container ps --filter "name=$SERVICE_NAME" --format "{{.ID}}"')
```

The call from Gitlab CI returns IDs of all containers running on the remote server.

My intention is to get only the ID of the specified `$SERVICE_NAME` that has only one container instance running.

As I checked on the remote machine, the output is equivalent to the following call:

```sh
docker container ps --filter "name=" --format "{{.ID}}"
```

so the empty variable value.

On the other hand, a call like:

```sh
docker container ps --filter "name='data_cleaner'" --format "{{.ID}}"
```

returns empty value, so it seems the variable value doesn't get passed to the remote machine.

I suppose the quotes surrounding the variable value cause the issue, but how to trim the value so that the quotes are removed?

Comment: try `CONTAINER_ID=$(ssh $USER@$TARGET_SERVER "docker container ps --filter name='$SERVICE_NAME' --format '{{.ID}}' ")`

Comment: I did that, and additionally, I added backslashes to the double quotes within the `docker container ps` command. And it worked :-) Please add your comment with my follow up as the answer.